# Which is the best way to filter with priority in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I need to filter/clean following a priorty list, for example, in this case my priority in the dimension group will be [A,B,C] meaning that for each id I want to check if there is a value for group A, if no I check if there is value for group B or C

```
id    group     value
1     A            :
1     B            2
1     C            7
2     A            1
2     B            3
2     C            5
3     A            :
3     B            :
3     C            2
```

The result of my filtering should be:

```
id    group     value
1     B            2
2     A            1
3     C            2
```

I can group by id and apply a function per group to define wich data is the right one. I can unstack the dataframe and put 'group' as columns and apply a function. Is there a simpler more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to replace the erroneous data with `NaN`, then drop those rows, sort the df by id and group, groupby id and take the first value:

```
In [361]:

df.value = df.value.replace(':', np.NaN)
df
Out[361]:
   id group value
0   1     A   NaN
1   1     B     2
2   1     C     7
3   2     A     1
4   2     B     3
5   2     C     5
6   3     A   NaN
7   3     B   NaN
8   3     C     2
In [376]:

df.dropna().sort(['id','group']).groupby('id').first()
Out[376]:
   group value
id            
1      B     2
2      A     1
3      C     2
```

Comment: Combining this with a categorical order, as my data is more complex than the A,B,C order, it's perfect